# Electron Application Not Launching from .app but Runs from Unix Executable

Tags: javascript, typescript, macos, electron

I'm facing an issue with my Electron application that I built using electron-react-boilerplate.

Steps to Reproduce:

1.I built the application using the following command:

```
npm run package
```

The build outputs to ./release/build/mac/myApplication.app.

2.I attempt to launch the myApplication.app. The application icon briefly appears in the macOS dock but fails to launch fully. Moreover, no error messages are displayed when I try to open it via the terminal.
However, when I manually navigate through the package contents:

```
Right-click on myApplication.app -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> MacOS
```

...and execute the Unix file named myApplication directly, the application starts up without any hitches.
For additional diagnostic information, I monitored the logs using macOS's Console utility. When executing the open ./myApplication.app command, the log displays:

```
LAUNCH: Launch failure with -10652/ <private> when launching .app application using cmd
```

**Question: What might be the reason for this behavior, and how can I ensure that the .app launches the application correctly?**

**EDIT**

setup version :

MacOS Monterey  version 12.6.7

Node version : 18.14.2

Electron version : 23.2.1

Electron-builder version: 23.6.0

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "UNIX Executable"?? Do you mean "executable file"?

Comment: Yes of kind Unix Executable file
you can check it by navigating 
show package contents - > Content -> MacOs and it will show up

Comment: Calling it a "UNIX executable" is overly specific and not really correct, so I'd avoid using that term. On macOS, it's a "Darwin" executable, but the details like that are largely irrelevant to your problem here. This looks like a bad build.

Comment: Sorry for that , But that's what the kind was , just thought writing as it is without editing anything

Comment: No worries, just trying to focus on the root problem here. You may want to specify which Electron version you're using, as well as which Node, so we can try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure , just edited the question and add the info !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out MacOs dont like process.cwd() That much

I used app.getPath('userData')

the weird think is why process.cwd() worked with the binary but not with
the app bundler